# Unique DataColumn comparison two DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

i have two data tables with the same column setup. Table "original" is used as a copy for comparison with table "edited", which contains mostly the same data but some rows may have been edited by a user.
The table "edited" is freely editable by users in Excel, hence the two-table system.

The tables may have varying primary keys resp. unique column values.

After editing is done I need to compare the two tables. 
If a unique column value has changed I need to treat that row as a new row i.e. use an INSERT instead of UPDATE query later on to the sql server. 
If any other but a unique column value is changed it will result in an UPDATE query.

I already have the lambda expression assuming the unique column is the first column in the tables.

```
var oldRows original.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r=> !edited.AsEnumerable()
        .Any(r2 => r[0].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == r2[0].ToString().Trim().ToLower()));

var newRows edited.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r=> !original.AsEnumerable() 
        .Any(r2 => r[0].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == r2[0].ToString().Trim().ToLower()));
```

Now, however, the requirement has changed to varying count and position of unique columns.
I can get all unique columns with a linq, but can't really work out how to join the two operations.

```
var uniqueColumns from DataColumn c in original.Columns where c.Unique select c;
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to work that into the expression?